# Exception handling and member variables

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

I have a simple Q.

If we have a class that has dynamically allocated member(or member that used dynamic allocation) and we often use that member what is the best way to handle some operation failing on that member.
Ofc there is try catch but Im not talking about that.

1)
Im talking about the fact that now the member is in the state it shouldnt be(and here Im not talking about leaking resources, Im talking about the fact that for example we wanted to push_back 100 elements to std::vector but we only added 47).

And now for example when we call the other method sendToDB we will be sending 47 instead of 100 items to DB. 
My guesstimates for solving is to have bool return values on all public methods(trying to go for all or nothing(aka push_back all 100 or push 0) and return false if we do manage to push 100, false if we push 0.

2)
But this still leaves the problem of the dynamically allocated members(for example shared_ptr). 
Does that mean that every method that uses it must do something like this:

```
bool MyClass::sendDataToDB()
{
    if (! m_DBConnection ) //m_DBConnection is std::shared_ptr
    return false;
   //...


}
```

Comment: Stop stealing my identity. (\/)(;,,;)(\/)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question, but would mentioning the basic, strong, and nothrow guarantees answer your question?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes no, since AFAIK they deal with handling exception where it happens, Im talking about this:simple example m_myStruct = new MyStruct(42); throws all good... but in some other public member function you are using m_myStruct(that is second part of my Q). First one is how to "remember" that ex occurred.

Comment: Example for first part of Q: Basically caller expected to add a list of 100 persons to my Class inner vector. new failed. Do I notify caller and let him take note of that or I do in class remembering to handle future calls. If 46 calls to push_back succeed do I do 46 pop_backs and return false?

Comment: You might be interested in scope guards.

Comment: BTW to make Q sound more familiar: my 47/100 example is talking about strong ex guarantee. But again that is not the problem. Problem is how the program "remembers" that exception happened aka adding failed.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl "If 46 calls to push_back succeed do I do 46 pop_backs and return false?" It depends on whether you want to provide the basic, the strong, or no guarantee. Is the object still usable with 46 successful push_backs? "how the program "remembers" that exception happened aka adding failed." I don't see why it would even need to remember it. The calling code will receive an exception and if that failure matters to the calling code, it will deal with it according to the exception safety guarantees that are documented by your function.

Comment: So you are saying(from object point of view) just leave myself in consistent state and rethrow ex so the caller can handle it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your problem, but I get this:

In your class you have an storage( something like `vector` ) and then you want to insert something in it, and operation may fail in middle of it. So you want to know whether insertion failed or operation complete! am I right? If answer is yes, I think the best solution for this is something like `iostream` that set a `fail` state in case of failure and you can check it later or can `throw exception` but in any case, setting `fail` bit can signal every one that my object is in a failed state

Comment: Yeah, my Q is mostly about how should a program "remember" something failed.

Comment: So I think design of your Q should be like `std::iostream`!

Comment: ah but that still leaves the second part of the Question ... do I check on every method entry if im in fail state and if so return false; or throw... seems ugly, but tbh i cant think of anything better

Comment: If your public methods change the state of the object, yes you should check your state, for example when we write an overloaded version of `<<` or `>>` operator for an stream, first we check whether stream is in failed state or not! but may be you can move state changes into few functions and then just check state in those few functions